# Performing time-based actions on node

Tags: neo4j

How do I trigger an action to be performed (set the property to something) on a node after a particular time in neo4j?

I know about the [graphaware's neo4j-expire](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-expire), but it only deletes nodes or relationships when the time is up, which is not what I want?

Comment: You need `apoc.periodic.schedule` procedure: https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_job_management

Comment: I think apoc.periodic.schedule will run the statement multiple times, right? I want the statement to run once when it's time

Comment: The task runs every second, you check the onset of the desired time, if it has arrived: launch the query and delete the task (`apoc.periodic.cancel`).

Comment: You can also use a combination of `apoc.date.expire` and `apoc.trigger` procedures.

Comment: apoc.periodic.cancel - Maybe I have 10000 (or more) nodes that needs to be invalidated after different time-ups, what about performance issues?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't think `apoc.date.expire` is doing anything other than adding a label and also setting the `ttl`. I think `apoc.trigger` wiill execute statement only when there is changes to the database. Am not sure how to use them together! Please explain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [apoc.date.expireIn](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_time_to_live_ttl) and [apoc.trigger](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_triggers) procedures. For example first add trigger:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('doVertexTask', '
      UNWIND {deletedRelationships} AS dRel
      WITH dRel WHERE type(dRel) = "taskRelation"
      WITH endNode(dRel) AS vertexNode WHERE "Vertex" IN labels(vertexNode)
      SET vertexNode.prop = rand()
      RETURN true', 
    {phase: "before"})
```

Then add the data and task:

```
MERGE (A:Vertex {id: 1})
CREATE (T:TASK)
CREATE (T)-[:taskRelation]->(A)
WITH A, T
CALL apoc.date.expireIn(T, 10, 's')
RETURN A, T
```

Comment: I tried it, but no property (`SET vertexNode.prop = rand()`) was set on node `A:Vertex` after 10 seconds.

Comment: It works for me. Check that all necessary configuration settings have been made (neo4.conf) for apoc.trigger and apoc.date.expireIn.

Comment: It finally work using a combination of `apoc.trigger.add` and `apoc.date.expireIn` when I enabled those procedures. Thanks, but one more thing, I don't understand this line `UNWIND {deletedRelationships} AS dRel`. I thought the `:taskRelation` relationship will be deleted, but it was not deleted because when I `MATCH` the relationship, it still shows me the `:Task` and `:Vertex` node connected even after the `prop` was set. That's also what I need, but I just want to understand what triggered that action.

Comment: @Emmanuel This is strange, because the expired node must be removed. Try look in the logs - if there is any error messages.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, the expired node was removed. Now I understand.